# How to conditionally find items by Tag in mongodb

Tags: php, sql, mongodb, nosql

I am new to `NoSQL` and `MongoDB` and I am a little puzzled on what type of queries I can do and how to do them. my knowledge is limited to simpler queries

I would like to make what I think its a complicated query within `MongoDB` instead of using `PHP` to sort it but I do not know if it is possible or how to do it.

I have a `tag` field within my collection that is an `array`. `{tag: ["blue","red","yellow","green","violet"]}`.

First level problem: Let says I want to find all `birds` that have the `tag` `blue & yellow & green`, where `blue` is a must have `tag` and any other colours are optional.

Second level problem: Then I would like to order the query so that the `birds` that have all the queried colours appear first.

Is it possible to create this query in mongoDB? and if it is How could I do it?

[image]

Comment: Post a sample document. Are the `tags` embedded at a `bird` document?

Comment: I've attached a screenshoot of my sample document. Yes, the `tags` are embedded into each `bird`

Comment: "Let says I want to find all birds that have the tag blue & yellow & green where blue is a must have tag and any other colours are optional" -> how would that result set be any different from when you search only for those which have the blue tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of this you will have to do in your application. In order to find all documents where a bird has the tag "blue", you can do this:

```
db.collection.find( { tag: "blue" } );
```

Which colours are optional doesn't matter, as you have to find by the required tag anyway.

After finding them, you need to do a sort. But sorting like you want (by their 3 colours) is not something you can do in MongoDB, and something you will have to do in PHP instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/). So for the next dataset:

```
{ "_id":ObjectId(...), "bird":1, "tags":["blue","red","yellow","green","violet"]}
{ "_id":ObjectId(...), "bird":2, "tags":["red","yellow","green","violet"] }
{ "_id":ObjectId(...), "bird":3, "tags":["blue","yellow","violet"] }
{ "_id":ObjectId(...), "bird":4, "tags":["blue","yellow","red","violet"] }
{ "_id":ObjectId(...), "bird":5, "tags":["blue"] }
```

we can apply next query:

```
colors = ["blue","red","yellow","green"];
db.birds.aggregate(
  { $match: {tags: 'blue'} },
  { $project: {_id:0, bird:1, tags:1} },
  { $unwind: '$tags' },
  { $match: {tags: {$in: colors}} },
  { $group: {_id:'$bird', score: {$sum:1}} },
  { $sort: {score:-1} },
  { $project: {bird:'$_id', score:1, _id:0} }
)
```

and will get result like this:

```
{
  "result" : [
    { "score" : 4, "bird" : 1 },
    { "score" : 3, "bird" : 4 },
    { "score" : 2, "bird" : 3 },
    { "score" : 1, "bird" : 5 }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```